# where can I find list of zero day vulnerability?

Tags: zero-day, vulnerability

I want to have list of zero day vulnerability, Could any one intuduce some site which annonce them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a) you appear to be asking for something which by its very definition can't exist, and b) listing vulnerabilities and exploits is not part of the remit of this site - there are already many which do this

Comment: There may be a site that compiles them for historical purposes, Jimmy Wales has a site for that. Sounds like a homework question to me. Early worms, ping of death and the like.

Answer (score 8):

A zero-day vulnerability is, by definition, one that has not been announced.

Comment: It is a vulnerability for which there is no patch.

Comment: @KDEx Not necessarily true. You can make a patch for a 0day if you know the general idea behind what is being exploited, even if you do not know the exploit itself. Let's say I told you I had a Linux kernel LPE that requires `mmap_min_addr` to be 0. I haven't disclosed the vulnerability, but now you know how to patch it (i.e. hardcode it to non-zero).

Answer (score 1):

Zero day which is not found anywhere. if you want to find a 0day you need to either research it and find it or buy one from the middle man like vupen or new one that kevin mithnick started